# Alinhar 4 divs sempre na horizontal, com tamanho proporcional ao tamanho da tela

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Preciso fazer com que 4 thumbnails acompanhem as largura da tela.

Exemplo:

DIV1 DIV2 DIV3 DIV4
As mesmas estão com um tamanho X, na horizontal em fileira, pegando toda a largura da tela.

Preciso que redimensionar a tela, a mesma ainda persista em 4 divs enfileiradas, com tamanhos proporcionais para aquele tipo de tela, e que preencha toda a largura.

Resumindo, elas devem acompanhar a largura da tela.

Como poderia fazer isto em Jquery ou css?

Comment: vc pode usar o bootstrap? Em caso afirmativo, basta setar as divs com a classe 'col-md-3': https://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/

Comment: Você poderia colocar o trecho do codigo em HTML, CSS e jquery para os especialistas poderem ajudar?

Comment: [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com) nesse caso é a melhor solução.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podes fazer isso da seguinte maneira:

```css
#listaHorizontal {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: table;              /* Transforma a div numa tabela */
    table-layout: fixed;         /* Utiliza o algoritmo de uma table fixed */
    border-collapse: separate;   /* Colapsa a tabela para poder adicionar o espaçamento */
    border-spacing: 5px 0px;     /* Adiciona o espaçamento */
}

/* Cria uma lista horizontal com espaçamento */
.item {display: table-cell;}
.item img{width:100%;}
```

```html
<ul id="listaHorizontal">
    <li class="item"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports"/></li>
    <li class="item"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/city"/></li>
    <li class="item"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/food"/></li>
    <li class="item"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/people"/></li>
</ul>
```

Desta forma podes adicionar ou remover items à lista, que esta irá se adaptar e ajustar automaticamente a `100%` do tamanho da sua `div pai`, sem ser preciso fazer nenhuma modificação no código CSS, apenas basta adicionar ou remover mais um item à lista - `<li class="item"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/people"/></li>`.

Aqui tens um [exemplo no jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/src_code/s4u5s42m/) para veres melhor isto em ação. Arrasta a janela do resultado, adiciona/remove um ou mais itens à lista.

Comment: Boa! Consegui! Era exatamente isto! Obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="x">
    <div class="DIVV">
    </div>
    <div class="DIVV">
    </div>
    <div class="DIVV">
    </div>
    <div class="DIVV">
    </div>
</div>

.x {
width: 100%;
}
.DIVV {
width: 25%;
}
```

Seria isso?

Answer (score 0):

Veja isto:

```css
.tbl {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}
.row {
  display: table-row;
}
.cel {
  display: table-cell;
}
div {
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="tbl">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cel">1
    </div>
    <div class="cel">2
    </div>
    <div class="cel">3
    </div>
    <div class="cel">4
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```